# Array.prototype.reduce() on arrays of one element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduction

In following `reduction + map` operations, no. 3 is puzzling me. Can anyone please explain why

```
// 1
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(x => x==3).reduce((x, y) => y) // -> 3, all good

// 2
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(x => x<=3).reduce((x, y) => 0) // -> 0, still good

// 3
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(x => x==3).reduce((x, y) => 0) // -> 3, hello?
```

**In other words:** how come the reduction on the array of one element ignores the map to `0` operation? This would ultimately be used on an array of objects, as in `.reduce((x,y) => y.attr)` which also returns `y` instead of `y.attr` for single element arrays.

Comment: there is only one element

Comment: part of the spec: "If the array has only one element (regardless of position) and no initialValue was provided, or if initialValue is provided but the array is empty, the solo value would be returned without calling callback." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: This obviously had to lead to some RTFM answer of sorts. Many thanks for calling it a day for me!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The filtered array contains only one element so reduce will return that value.

Read the docs :

> **If the array has only one element (regardless of position)** and no initialValue was provided, or if initialValue is provided but the array is empty, the solo value would be returned without calling callback.

For more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce